# What (hardware/software) projector setup is needed to project both displays?

Tags: display, projector

I have a (non-Thunderbolt) 17" MacBook Pro connected to an external display. I want to project both screens (from MBP and external displays) each onto separate screens.

Is there a way to do this?
And how to set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to have your macbook output to two displays, which it won't do easily/willingly.

There are a couple hacks...either doing the display output over USB or using a matrox display. See more info: [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1307175)

One *really* hacky solution might be to output via air display to and iPad (hooked up to a projector)for the 2nd monitor. I'll buy you a beer if you make that work. :-)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Somehow I don't think I'll be able to earn that beer.  :)